# Can't connect to MySQL database from Laravel, even though I created the required user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm getting this error when I open a view that requires data:

`` SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `books`) ``

I created the homestead@localhost user in MySQL with the specified password, but I'm still getting the error... What might cause this and how can i fix it? Thanks! :) (I already tried restarting the `php artisan serve` process and running `php artisan config:clear`...)

Comment: Is mysql and the webserver on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

This is really stupid but Laravel was lying about the password it was using; it was actually "secret" as defined in the .env file!